# how to convert string labels to int for image classification using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I have data stored in the format [png,boundingbox,labels]. I need to convert the labels(string) to int datatype and then map them to image. Totally I have 3 categories of labels ex:(apple, Orange,blueberry). if simple dictionary would work how to map them with image.

Comment: what do you mean by "map them with image"? They are corresponging with bounding boxes, as it is detection task, right?

Comment: Could you add the code you have got so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am using bounding boxes to crop the image in order to convert detection to classification. Now I need to convert the string labels to int and then to one hot encoded labels.